# Save listbox to SQL Server database using Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to save list of items shown in a listbox in my service

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string DisplayVersion { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set;}
}

public List<MyItem> GetListapp()
{
    List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
    string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
    {
        foreach (string sbnm in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(sbnm))
            {
                string appVersion = (string)subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion");
                string pub = (string)subkey.GetValue("Publisher");
                String app = Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));

                if (app != "")
                    items.Add(new MyItem() { DisplayName = app, DisplayVersion = appVersion, Publisher = pub });
            }
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

I have made a database listapp with table ID, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher

My `model.context.cs` is:

```
public partial class listappEntities : DbContext
{
    public listappEntities() : base("name=listappEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Table> Table { get; set; }
}
```

I used ADO.NET Entity Data Model to connect to database and I have already `Model.cs` like that :

```
public partial class Table
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string DisplayName { get; set; }
     public string DisplayVersion { get; set; }
     public string Publisher { get; set; }
}
```

When I click the button, I can see listofprograme  from my service

```
private void btnGIA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        MYS.ServiceClient pk = new MYS.ServiceClient();
        listBox.ItemsSource = pk.GetListapp();
}
```

How can I save this list in my database or update if exists?

And please how can I query to show saved program  in other listbox that I will create.

Comment: uh, well, you're using `class MyItem` to store your list from the GUI? and you wish to save it to `partial class Table`? if i may add my question, did you use [`Entity Framework`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6), if so, you'll need to map `MyItem` to `Table`, then save it using `listappEntities` instance. i wanna write an answer but not sure.

Comment: please can you write i will try if that will work for me

Comment: use web service for MyItem class